# HTMLCollection() Values and Names to JSON

Tags: javascript, json, htmlcollection

**Problem:**

Two forms, in hidden divs, which appear when you press the coressponding button. The Input gets parsed to JSON and sent with a request.
I can't use `form` or  `fieldset` to wrap around the form for different reasons, so I used:

`form = document.getElementById('formularEins').getElementsByTagName('input');`

When I was still able to use `form.elements` (before I realised that the .elements property is not supported on fieldsets by IE) I used this to generate JSON from the input:

*(In this case `form = document.getElementsByClassName('formOne')[0];`*

```
Const formToJSON = elements => [].reduce.call(elements, (data, element) => {
    if (isCheckbox(element)) {
    //data[element.name] = (data[element.name] || []).concat(element.value);
    data[element.name] = element.value;
  } else if (isMultiSelect(element)) {
    data[element.name] = getSelectValues(element);
  } else {
    data[element.name] = element.value;
  }
}
return data;
},);
```

**Question:**

How can you convert the Input to JSON for a HTMLCollection and its items like above?

I tried - and failed with different versions of the following:

```
   var formToJSON = function formToJSON(form) {
       for (var i = 0; i < form.length; i++) {
       var item = form[i]; 
       data[item.name] = item.value; }
   };
```

Comment: Small note: `var formToJSON = function(form) {...}` or `function formToJSON(form) {...}` (or `formToJSON = form => {...}`), don't repeat the function name in a variable function assignment.

Comment: Also, `[].reduce.call()` is not very idiomatic (but I know why you did it -- `.reduce()` doesn't exist on `HTMLCollection`), but how about [`Array.from(form).reduce({...})`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from).

Comment: @msanford thank you! The `formToJSON = form => {...}` was what I had but IE somehow wouldn't work with it so I changed it to `var formToJSON = function(form) {...}` but that was a bit overkill.

Comment: Just noting that the name you give it in that type of assignment is ignored. Try it with different names: `var a = function b(c) {console.log(c)}` and then `b("hello")` will throw `ReferenceError: b is not defined`. Kind of what one expects, but worth nothing. Also, too bad you can't use `=>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define data variable as object. Try following formToJSON function.

```
var formToJSON = function(form) {
  var data = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < form.length; i++) {
    var item = form[i];
    data[item.name] = item.value;
  }
  return data;
}
```